# How do I load my vim python script after all the buffers are loaded?

Tags: python, vim, neovim

I'm following [this tutorial](http://candidtim.github.io/vim/2017/08/11/write-vim-plugin-in-python.html) on creating a vim plugin from python. I was trying to use the knowledge I got to access the first line of the current buffer, so I wrote:

```
let s:plugin_root_dir = fnamemodify(resolve(expand('<sfile>:p')), ':h')

python3 << EOF
import sys
from os.path import normpath, join
import vim
plugin_root_dir = vim.eval('s:plugin_root_dir')
python_root_dir = normpath(join(plugin_root_dir, '..', 'python'))
sys.path.insert(0, python_root_dir)
import sample
EOF
```

and in my python file I wrote:

```py
import vim

vim.command("sign define gdlinterror text=✕")
vim.command("sign define gdlintwarning text=")
print(vim.current.buffer[0])
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing function provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
Error invoking 'python_execute' on channel 4 (python3-script-host):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/chrismg/Projects/Python/sampleplugin/python/sample.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(vim.current.buffer[0])
  File "/home/chrismg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pynvim/api/buffer.py", line 45, in __ge
titem__
    return self.request('nvim_buf_get_lines', i, i + 1, True)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So when I tried the same commands within vim using `:python3` it surprised me that it worked very well, but not in the python script. So when I checked the `len` of the `vim.current.buffer` I got 0. I think this is the amount of lines in the file, which is false in my case, so I started wondering, is this python script being executed before the buffer is being loaded? This would explain why there is an index out of bounds error. However, I don't know how to run the vim plugin after the buffer is finished loading. 
Any help in finding out what to do is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Autocommand [`VimEnter`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#VimEnter) is fired after initialization and loading all buffers.

Comment: @phd That's great but how do I use the python script once VimEnter is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, even when you're writing plug-in code in Python, you'll still be handling Vimscript events, accessing Vimscript variables, using Vimscript for mapping keys and so on. Writing plug-ins in Python essentially means writing them in Python *and* Vimscript.

You should use your main Python module (`sample.py`) to define functions rather than execute code at the top-level. Then you can use mappings or auto-commands to trigger those functions on specific events.

For example, to trigger compilation on pressing F5:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F5> :python3 sample.compile()<CR>
```

Or to add an auto-gemerated license comment to the top with `<Leader>L`

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>L :0put =py3eval('sample.license_text()')<CR>
```

Or to check syntax of Ruby files when they're loaded:

```
autocmd FileType ruby python3 sample.check_syntax('ruby')
```

As you can see, while you're being able to use Python code here, you're mostly doing so by calling the `:python3` command or using the `py3eval()` function, but still using quite a bit of Vimscript in the process. So, in a way, you end up having to understand really well how Vimscript works to be able to write Vim plug-ins effectively.

The same is also quite true for using the `vim` module from Python. Since you're mainly using it to access Vimscript variables and the way you have access to Vim objects closely matches what Vim functions offer you, knowing Vimscript well will help you there.

Being able to write Vim plug-ins in Python *can* be quite handy when you're using it to accomplish something that would be impossible or very hard to do in pure Vimscript, such as accessing web resources (for example, online dictionary lookups), parsing complex file formats such as XML or CSV with full fidelity, accessing databases or network servers, or evaluating syntax of Python code (since you can easily use Python to parse and run Python snippets.)

But even in those cases, it makes most sense to implement most of the plug-in using Vimscript and use Python only as necessary to implement the parts you can't implement directly with Vimscript.

If you'd like to learn more Vimscript and how to write plug-ins with it, I strongly recommend [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) by Steve Losh. It's an excellent resource if you're interested in creating Vim plug-ins.

Comment: Thank You! I will definitely try this practice, as well as read the book.